# Jest for vuex, test different return values for a same action

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

For a component that looks like: (simplified)

```
@Component
export default class MyComp extends Vue {

  private status = 'error';

  async create() {
    const result = await this.$store.dispatch('create', payload);
    if (result.code) {
      this.status = 'error';
    } else {
      this.status = 'success';
    }
  }
}
```

In the spec I tried mocking the create action with

```
    actions = {
        create: () => jest.fn()
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ code: true, message: 'error' }) // mock an error on first call
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ code: false }) // mock success on second call
    }
```

Then I call create twice

```
    wrapper.vm.create();
    console.log(wrapper.vm.$data.status);
    wrapper.vm.create();
    console.log(wrapper.vm.$data.status);
```

this.status doesn't change.

Next thing I tried is a single action mock

```
create: () => ({ code: true, message: 'error' })
```

Then change the action during the test

```
    wrapper.vm.create();
    console.log(wrapper.vm.$data.status);
    actions.create = () => ({ code: false });
    store.hotUpdate({ actions });
    wrapper.vm.create();
    console.log(wrapper.vm.$data.status);
```

still, status doesn't change.

How do I go about testing this simple if/else logic?

**EDIT:**

Adding console logs inside if and else branches I can see that the mocked action in the test does work (coverage is 100%) and returns the correct data. So `this.status=xx` is executed each time.

But it doesn't look like `this.status` is linked to `wrapper.vm.$data.status`.

I tried all manners of nexttick() and forceUpdate(), still no luck.
wrapper.vm.$data.status doesn't change when this.status is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found just the right mix of nexttick and forceupdate that makes the code work.

```
    actions.create = () => Promise.resolve({ code: false });
    store.hotUpdate({ actions });
    await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
    wrapper.vm.create();
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.status).toEqual('success');
```

If I remove the nexttick or either of the forceupdate, the test doesn't pass.